# How do I make Coded UI wait for WPF application to fully load through C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I have a application that starts, then a splash screen shows with a progress of loading, and then the main WPF application window appears. I want the Coded UI to wait until the main window appears before continue on with the test. How can i wait through C# code? Please note the main application load without specific timebound(no defined time), Sometimes it may take 40s or 2 mins or 5mins or even more.  How can I wait for splash screen loading gets completed and till the main application displayed successfully through C#?.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void verifyApplicationMaximized()
    {
        ApplicationUnderTest _app = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(_appPath);
        _app.WaitForControlReady();

        if (_app.Title.Equals("TTY® 2000") && !_app.Maximized)
            _app.Maximized = true;

        // Assert check
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also wait for a control on the main window of your application to exist via [WaitForControlExist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee823173.aspx) method. Relying on a property value may make your test fragile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WaitForControlPropertyEqual` method.

```
_app.WaitForControlPropertyEqual(ApplicationUnderTest.PropertyNames.Title, 
    "TTY® 2000", 1000 * 60 * 15);
//im using 15mins
```

While this is an arbitrarily high as a value, it should serve your purpose.